# how to create a window in firefox that looks like "lookup" window in mac os

Tags: firefox-addon

I am trying to design a firefox extension which shows some information for the selected word in the page.

for those information I like to have a window with no boarders and with a pointer pointing to the selected word. something like this picture (lookup feature in mac os):

[sample1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eN7E3.jpg)

here is another example from firefox itself:

[sample2](http://i1-news.softpedia-static.com/images/news-700/Firefox-22-Aurora-Adds-Support-for-HTML5-Desktop-Notifications.png?1365575637)

any idea on how I can create this kind of windows is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for a [Panel](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/panel.html) to do this and you could likely use the [Selection](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/selection.html) module as well to work with the text.  However you'll find it a little challenging to get your panel to point to the text like you want, currently the Panel doesn't easily support positioning like that.

Comment: Cool, I didn't know about add-on SDK! I have been creating extensions for Firefox the old fashion way using XUL. life is much easier now thanks to you. the only thing as you mentioned is the position of the panel and I still try to figure out how to create that triangle pointer.